# Normalize styles across browsers with system fonts function

Tags: html, css, webfonts

I downloaded [mvasilkov/systematize](https://github.com/mvasilkov/systematize/blob/master/README.md) latest release and tried to input `npm install —save systematize` in terminal but got this:`⸨░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠇ rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session 5b64df302bdd24b`
) and font didn’t change to SF when I open websites on safari.
So I wonder is there any following steps I can take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like what you've send is scss alternative for normalize.css (https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css) and if you're familiar HTML and CSS and don't want to get in touch with NPM you could use css version and just include this file: https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/latest/normalize.css in your code. This should add all the rules you need and behave as expected.

Answer (score 0):

`npm install -save systemize`

- npm: binary file
- install: tell npm to install something
- -save: save this module to the dependencies to import into your app
- systemize: the name of the module you are installing.

You'll probably want to import the systemize module into your JS bundle to use within your application.

Finally, it looks like you can use those class-names and systemize will automatically apply the effect you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In your folder:

`npm init` (press Enter through all the steps)
`npm install --save systemize`

Comment: what do you get when you do `node -v`?

Answer (score 0):

`npm` is a package manager for Nodejs. Make sure you have [Nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) installed then you can run `npm`